# Python Flask update var after new request

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, countdown

I have created a simple script in Python (i am a newby). Everything is working as needed, except for one minor issue.

**My project:**
I send a request to my server through http:
{ip-of-server}/?speed=999&time=8&cents=50

This will display a countdown timer in your shell. Counting down from 8 to 0 in this case. That works well. When I send {ip-of-server}/?speed=499&time=8&cents=50 it will count down twice as fast. This is as needed.

**The issue i am facing:**
During countdown, i need to be able to send a new request to my server. It should update the countdown with the new values. At the moment it will create 2 countdowns. Which is correct if you read the script, but not what I need. I need some help how to just update the existing countdown.

**My code:**

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)
import time

@app.route('/', methods = ["GET"])

def post():
    speed = float(request.args["speed"])
    thetime = request.args["time"]
    cents = request.args["cents"]

    print('\n')
    print('AccuView Digital:')
    print('Speed:', speed,' Time:', thetime,' Cents:', cents)
    print('-------------------------------')

    def countdown(thetime):
        while thetime:
            mins, secs = divmod(thetime, 60)
            timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
            print('Tijd:', timer, end="\r")
            time.sleep((speed+1)/1000)
            thetime -= 1
            if thetime == 0:
                print('Werp geld in\n') 
    countdown(int(thetime))
    return '1'

app.run(host='192.168.1.107', port= 8090)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is working fine as you said yourself. So what's happening right now is that flask is creating threads to serve your requests. You send 1st request, flask starts a counter on one thread and when you send another request, flask starts another thread and another counter runs on that thread. Both threads have their own values of `speed`, `thetime` and `cents` and one thread cannot change the value of a variable in another thread.

So what we want to do is to access/modify the value of variables from any thread. One easy solution for this is to use global variables so that these variables are accessible from all the threads.

**Solution:**

1. Make `speed`, `thetime` and `cents` as global variables so they are modifiable from any thread.
2. When we receive a request, check if a counter is already running (we can do it by checking if value of global variable `thetime` is `0`).
3. We know if an existing counter is running or not, now just update the values of global variables.
4. If there is no existing counter running, then start the counter (call the method `countdown()`). Else we don't need to do anything (we have already updated the values of global variables in previous step so the existing counter is updated).

**Code:**

```
import time
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

# We create global variables to keep track of the counter
speed = thetime = cents = 0


@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def post():
    global speed, thetime, cents

    # Check if previous counter is running
    counter_running = True if thetime else False

    thetime = int(request.args["time"])
    speed = float(request.args["speed"])
    cents = request.args["cents"]

    print('\n')
    print('AccuView Digital:')
    print('Speed:', speed, ' Time:', thetime, ' Cents:', cents)
    print('-------------------------------')

    def countdown():
        global thetime, speed
        while thetime:
            mins, secs = divmod(thetime, 60)
            timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
            print('Tijd:', timer, end="\r")
            time.sleep((speed + 1) / 1000)
            thetime -= 1
            if thetime == 0:
                print('Werp geld in\n')

    # If existing counter is running, then we don't start another counter
    if not counter_running:
        countdown()
    return '1'


app.run(host='192.168.1.107', port= 8090)
```

---

**Code (so that we can interrupt sleep):**

```
import time
import threading
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

# We create global variables to keep track of the counter
speed = thetime = cents = 0
sleep_speed = threading.Event()


@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def post():
    global speed, thetime, cents, sleep_speed

    # Check if previous counter is running
    counter_running = True if thetime else False

    thetime = int(request.args["time"])
    speed = float(request.args["speed"])
    cents = request.args["cents"]

    # Make sure to interrupt counter's sleep
    if not sleep_speed.is_set():
        sleep_speed.set()
    sleep_speed.clear()

    print('\n')
    print('AccuView Digital:')
    print('Speed:', speed, ' Time:', thetime, ' Cents:', cents)
    print('-------------------------------')

    def countdown():
        global thetime, speed
        while thetime:
            mins, secs = divmod(thetime, 60)
            timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
            print('Tijd:', timer, end="\r")
            sleep_speed.wait((speed + 1) / 1000)
            thetime -= 1
            if thetime == 0:
                print('Werp geld in\n')

    # If existing counter is running, then we don't start another counter
    if not counter_running:
        countdown()
    return '1'


app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8090)
```

Comment: This works well. The only issue i have is when i send 6000000 as speed, it does not work anymore. While sending speed 499 and 999 does. The device sending me uses speed 6000000 to stop the counter and after that sends a new request with time and speed 499 or 999.

Comment: @user3014636 well it does work when you send speed=6000000 but it goes to sleep. So now when you send sleep=999 it doesn't work because the thread is already in sleep mode and there is no way to wake it up. So instead of using `time.sleep`, you should use `Event.wait()`. Updated the answer with both codes..

Comment: Working but having one issue. The first GET request that is being send after speed=600000 is not captured (it does when i send it using the browser, but it doesn't when receiving it from the iOT device). But when i delete all code and only create a listener for the iOT is see it coming in, so first speed=6000000 and after that i see speed=999 (or 499) coming in, but this is not captured. I need to send it twice to make it work.

Comment: Anyone an idea? I am stuck here.

Comment: @user3014636 did you check with 2nd code?
`Code (so that we can interrupt sleep):`

Comment: Yes I did. And I am using that. It's working but not the first time it stays in sleep.